# C# GetMethods() missing some methods

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to use the GetMethods() function on a class I've created. It used to work, but recently a couple more methods were added and getMethods doesn't retrieve them.
The methods are public, aren't inherited, and seemingly aren't different from the ones that existed there in the first place.
I tried setting several binding flags, including Public, NonPublic, Instance, Static and FlattenHierarchy.
This is what I'm doing:

```
ClassA classInstance = new ClassA();           
Type t = classInstance.GetType();
methodlist = t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Methods.txt");
foreach(var item in methodlist)
{
    file.WriteLine(item);
}
```

In the class I have:

```
public ref class ClassA
{
public:
.
.
.
bool methodA();
bool methodB();
}
```

Yet in Methods.txt I only see methodA. With all the flags I also see the constructors\destructors and the inherited methods.
The call to GetMethods() is from C# code, the class ClassA is in C++. 
What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure your C# is compiled against your latest C++ code?

Comment: I second mjwills. Try cleaning out old build artifacts and try again.

Comment: If you had an old Methods.txt and your swallowing exceptions then that would explain it as the write to C:\ will fail without elevation.

Comment: I erase the Methods.txt after every time and it seems that there is no problem with that - I will try and rebuild all the relevant projects from scratch.

Comment: As @mjwills said - I just compiled them in the wrong order (C# then C++), and it obviously haven't updated the methods. Thank you all!